# Unable to yield russian characters the same as input in perl on windows environment

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I have a set of russian string which I am passing as a input to a perl script to store the same into database but when I print the same string on windows console I get characters from input. Also, the database has different characters inserted in the column. Could you please share some pointers for the issue.

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem. Generally when data enters a perl program it needs to be decoded into a code-point string, and when it leaves a perl program it needs to encoded to a byte string. But there are a lot of ways this can be done and variables involved that you'll need to tell us more about the problem (i.e. sample input, perl code you're using, database you're using) for more help.

Comment: I am giving input string as Стив getting it displayed on windows console which prints it as ЛЫУР while the in the database the column value shows as Noea . The database i am using is mssql and I am running a perl script as a bat file

Comment: It would really help if you could supply: 1) a hex-dump of the input file; 2) the perl program which reads the input file, stores the word in the mssql database and reads it out again; 3) a hex-dump of what perl prints as output.

Answer (score 1):

Decode inputs. Encode outputs.

---

What's the encoding of the data in your database?

Say it's UTF-8. You'd use something like the following:

```
use Encode qw( decode );
my $row = ...;
$row->{text_field} = decode('UTF-8', $row->{text_field});
```

---

What's the encoding expected by your console?

You can find the answer to this by running `chcp` at the prompt, and prepending `cp` to the number. For example, on a machine where the encoding to use is `cp437`, you'd ge tthe following output:

```
>chcp
Active code page: 437
```

You'd handle the encoding as follows:

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp437)';
```

Comment: Could you clarify what OS/flavor 'chcp' is related to the code page?  Under Ubuntu Linux 12.04 it seems to be part of the nilfs-tools package and is used to change NILFS checkpoints (at least on my system).

Comment: @DavidO, it's a Windows tool. The user is using Windows.